# Which Disk to replace first ? Predictive Failure or Failed Disk

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid5, diskmanagement

We have a HPDL380 G6 server ( running 2003 R2) with 1 failed disk and 1 predictive failure.

Total 4 Disks configured with RAID5.

I will be replacing disks, **Now question is which disk should I replace first and why ?**

Thank You
JP

Answer (score 3):

There is only one option: The failed disk. If you replace the "predictive failure" one first, you will have two missing disks in the array and loose all data.

**Important: Make sure you have a current and tested backup pronto, before you do anything else. It's kind of likely the array will fail during recovery ...**

BTW: The same order is necessary for a RAID6.

Comment: He should replace them both. But indeed in the order you gave.

Comment: @Tom: I hope that this should be self-evident :)

Comment: I have a backup of the data, just wanted to be clear on order to replace disks. Failure is imminent due to server is been in this state for a while.

Comment: Oh, and get rid of 2003. This is EOL for three years now.